# How to show range slider value on html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having a range slider and I would like to show that range slider value on the HTML canvas and the value should always change on the canvas when the range slider value changes.

```
slider.oninput = function() {
output.innerHTML = this.value;     //this gets the range slider value every time it changes
var rangevalue = output.innerHTML; //and sends it to drawToCanvas function.
drawToCanvas(rangevalue);
}
```

The rangevalue is sent to drawToCanvas function but it doesn't show on the canvas. Canvas shows "undefined" and I don't know why because drawToCanvas function takes rangevalue as a parameter and stores it to a variable "rangevalue". When I check the value of rangevalue on console.log the value is correct and changes every time I change the value on range slider but still canvas shows "undefined"?

```
ctx.fillText(rangevalue, 50, 95); //here I try to show the value of rangevalue variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have this issue, possibly a typo in drawToCanvas.

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" max="1000000">
<div id="output"></div>
<canvas id="cnv" height="1000" width="1000"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d")
    slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value; //this gets the range slider value every time it changes
        var rangevalue = output.innerHTML; //and sends it to drawToCanvas function.
        drawToCanvas(rangevalue)
    }
function drawToCanvas(rangevalue){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
    ctx.fillText(rangevalue, 100, 100) 
}
</script>
```